# Where can I find the typings file "zone.d.ts"?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

The file [globals.d.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/globals.d.ts) references the file **typings/zone/zone.d.ts** but there isn't a typings directory in the repository nor is there a **zone** directory in [Boris Yankov's DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) repository. Where can I find **zone.d.ts** or the typings directory **zone**? Google doesn't produce any results.

Answer (score 1):

In `modules/angular2` run

> tsd reinstall

This will create the typings directory defined in `modules/angular2/tsd.json` with all the required typing directories including **zone**.

Beware that the reinstall will overwrite any existing typings directory.